# Why does data augmentation (ImageDataGenerator) give me very poor accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I implemented ResNet in TensorFlow ([similar to this](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/resnet50.py)) and trained it on the CIFAR-10 dataset. Without any data augmentation, I get 99.9% train accuracy and 73% validation accuracy. I didn't change the model and tried to use [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) for data augmentation:

```py
# ----- data augmentation: -----
BATCH_SIZE = 128

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

datagen.fit(x_train)

train_generator = datagen.flow(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True
)

# ----- train model: -----
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(1e-4),
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model_history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    steps_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=10
)
```

However, now with the augmented data generator, I get a training and validation accuracy of about 10%. I tried other transformations (rotation_range, width_shift_range, etc.) but none of them have much effect. So, why is ImageDataGenerator giving me such poor results?

Comment: You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141540/image-augmentation-makes-performance-worse) answer. Also, I found a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/moritzhambach/Image-Augmentation-in-Keras-CIFAR-10-/blob/master/CNN%20with%20Image%20Augmentation%20(CIFAR10).ipynb) in which the authors have performed image augmentation on CIFAR-10 dataset.

Comment: *error of about 10%* So you have 90% accuracy on both training and validation set which is good for this dataset.

Comment: @Frightera Sorry -- I meant to say "**accuracy** of about 10%". I fixed my original post.

Comment: try removing datagen.fit(x_train). You only need to fit the train set if you are using featurewise_center,=True or   samplewise_center=True. or  featurewise_std_normalization=True or     samplewise_std_normalization=True or
 zca_whitening=True, also did you rescale the pixels?